# MYSQL Exception in prepared statement to use the right syntax near '?'

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have written the following code. But I am getting the MySQL Exception to use the right syntax near '?'. 
Can you help me to resolve this issue?

```
public static void inbox(String username) {
    String query_recipient = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name FROM user_info WHERE username = '" + username + "' ";
    String query = "SELECT sub, msg FROM message WHERE recipient = ?";
    Statement s = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    int userId = 0;

    try {
        s = Connect.con.createStatement();
        rs = s.executeQuery(query_recipient);
        rs.next();
        userId = rs.getInt("user_id");

        ps = Connect.con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, userId);

        rs1 = ps.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs1.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs1.getString("sub"));
            System.out.println(rs1.getString("msg"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserBAL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } //end catch
} //end inbox()
```

Edit: This is the error message

```
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2738)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1617)
at msg_pkg.MsgBAL.inbox(MsgBAL.java:82)
at msg_pkg.MsgBAL.main(MsgBAL.java:116)
```

Comment: Check if userId is not null.. And stacktrace also would be helpfull

Comment: Can you please share the error message?

Comment: Also, you probably know this but I'll state it anyway:  the "query" rather than the "query_recipient" approach is the correct one.

Comment: The error message is included in the edited question.

Comment: I think you shouldn't pass `query` to `executeQuery`. It's been already prepared.

Comment: I have 2 separate queries, that's why need to distinguish them by using different variables.

Comment: @SorathAsnani what BadZen means is that you shouldn't build a string catenating parameter values. Use ? as placeholders and setInt(), setString(), etc.

Comment: Okay, I got the point. Thanks for the correction @1010

Answer (score 3):

I see some mistakes in your code:

1. You're passing a SQL statement to a prepared statement... and that is not only not necesary, it is wrong. Check [the documentation for the `executeQuery()` method of prepared statements.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29)
2. After you retreive the users result set, you simply move to the next row... It may work, but the right way to do it is: go to the *first* row of the result set (with `rs.first()`).

   That same thing happens some lines below: you move to the next row of the messages result set; you should first move *before the first row*, and then move to the next (while there's a next row).
3. (Personal suggestion) The first query is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Since you're already using prepared statements, why don't you use a prepared statement to get the user id?
4. (Personal suggestion), instead of using the `try ... catch` style (which is not incorrect), I think it would be better to use the [`try` with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) style. That way you force the resources (in this case, the prepared statement(s)) to close as soon as your program is done with them.

Let's clean up your code a bit:

```java
public static void inbox(String username) {
    /* 
       First: Avoid SQL injection risks: use a prepared statement 
       to get user data.
    */
    String qryRec = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name "
                  + "FROM user_info "
                  + "WHERE username = ?";
    String qryMsg = "SELECT sub, msg "
                  + "FROM message "
                  + "WHERE recipient = ?";
    ResultSet rsRec = null, 
              rsMsg = null;

    // "try-with-resources"
    try(
        PreparedStatement psRec = Connect.con.prepareStatement(qryRec);
        PreparedStatement psMsg = Connect.con.prepareStatement(qryMsg);
    ) {
        // Set the parameter for psRecipient, and execute the query
        psRec.setString(1, username);
        rsRec = psRec.executeQuery(); // No need to pass the query 
                                      // as an argument here; it's
                                      // already prepared

        // Go to the first row of rsRecipient
        rsRec.first();

        // Set the parameter for psMessage, and execute the query
        psMsg.setInt(1, rsRecipient.getInt("user_id");
        rsMsg = psMmsg.executeQuery(); // No need to pass the query 
                                       // as an argument here; it's
                                       // already prepared

        // Go to the resultset "header" (i.e. before the first row
        rsMsg.beforeFirst();
        while(rsMsg.next()) {
            System.out.println(rsMsg.getString("sub"));
            System.out.println(rsMsg.getString("msg"));
        }

        // Remember to close the result sets
        try {
            if(rsRec != null)
                rsRec.close();
        } catch(SQLException e) {/*Ignore*/} finally {rsRec = null;}

        try {
            if(rsMsg != null)
                rsMsg.close();
        } catch(SQLException e) {/*Ignore*/} finally {rsMsg = null;}
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please don't just dump code, also describe how you think it fixes the problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you... just corrected

Answer (score 0):

There is **no need** to pass `query` as a parameter to

```
rs1 = ps.executeQuery(query);
```

so just take it off

```
rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
```